# Unclickable menu item which is not greyed out in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a menu item in my overflow menu with no icon at all and I am using it as an information to the user which should not have been seen right away.

When I make it disabled, it will be greyed out. I want to make an item that is not clickable? How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this, you should specify your own style for `ListView` item with `selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
</selector>
```

It is a code taken from default button's xml. I changed it so that in state `android:state_enabled="false"` it still uses normal background.

You can change it to whatever you want your item to look like.

Put it into xml file called for example `my_item.xml`, put it into drawable directory and then in xml where you create your item, set it's background to `background="@drawable/my_item"`.

Comment: Are you even read the question? I am asking this for menu items. I can set the item as a custom view and use your way of course. MenuItems do not have background or something.

Comment: @tasomaniac Yes, but you can also create your own style for `ListView` item. The rest is as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: With custom items of course you can do what you want. I have asked if I can do it with MenuItem?